# Google Managed VMs error while deploying

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, managed-vm

We just moved to VMs and while deploying we are having issues in Java Environment. The error is 
**Error Create Config Bucket failed. during VmCreateConfigBucket.**

Then tried all the steps in the Google Page - deploying to Production. Nothing seems to work. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/sdk)

Then We manually tried to create the buckets in Google Console. Retried our deployement but got the same error.

```
DETAILED Error message in the LOG :: Unable to update:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal problem encountered during deployment. Please refer to the logs for more information.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.isServing(AppVersionUpload.java:900)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.access$100(AppVersionUpload.java:41)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload$2.call(AppVersionUpload.java:779)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload$2.call(AppVersionUpload.java:776)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.retryWithBackoff(AppVersionUpload.java:1029)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.commit(AppVersionUpload.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the image did the trick for me.

```
docker rmi <image>
```

Then:

```
gcloud preview app deploy --version=my_version my_dir/app.yaml
```